# A TV show about Space Station

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I watched a TV show about space station back when between 1995 to 2005 (Sorry I can't remember the exact time).

The episodes that I remember:

- A guy created a fruit which was a mix between coconut and avocado.
- A space shuttle was leaving the space station and suddenly crashed in the space station and killed all people on space shuttle.
- There was mysterious black pyramid they found in a space ship or something.
- They found a rock from another planet which was melting the space station because the main material created the space station was sensitive with the rock.
- They had to deal with a specimen of smallpox they carried from the Earth to the space station for studying and it broke out.
- The space station was on fire or something, they had to evacuate all and one guy left behind his robots which looked like Wall-E.

Anyone who knows the name of this TV show, please let me know. The TV show may not be American because back then in my country they were broadcasting a lot of shows from Australia and Canada.

Comment: Some paragraphs or even a list would make this a much better question!

Comment: @AidanO then why don't you help them out with a little editing?

Comment: @sarge_smith Time permitting I would have, I thought some feedback to VuDinh  would be better that just down voting (which I didn't, but considered) the question and moving on!

Comment: Thanks very much to whoever edited my post. I didn't even remember that I posted this 3 years ago. Came across it today and was stunned that it was me who posted this question. Thanks for all the help, folks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is almost certainly [Space Island One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Island_One).

- The coconut-avocado hybrid (developed by Lyle Campbell) was in Season 2, Episode 2 "Split Allegiances".  (I think this is sufficiently unusual to confirm the identification.)
- In Season 2, Episode 5, "Lost Property", the shuttle Raven crashed into the station after passing by (it had one more satellite to handle before returning to Earth, but had not docked with the station); an educational toy wreaks havoc.
- In Season 1, Episode 7, "The Barrier of Second Attention", a black pyramid (with orange and black lower section with cuneiform-like writing on it) with a base approximately one meter by one meter moves into the station mysteriously and hovers in the simulated gravity.  The pyramid left behind a figurine/urn with ashes in it.  Some of the writing translated to "Greetings from great voyager Noah.  At last his earthly ashes can be received among the stars."
- In Season 1, Episode 3, "Quarantine", a Mars lander returned and the station scientists were given permission for first examination of the samples.  One rock sample contained a microbe which ate acrylics--"half the station is made of acrylics" (presumably hyperbole as one might expect from the situation).
- In Season 2, Episode 7, "Not in My Back Yard", a smallpox specimen is taken to the station and it is feared that the smallpox virus was released after crew members begin to display smallpox-like symptoms.

I cannot yet identify that last described episode (it might have been the last episode of the series), but it is consistent with the show in general.  There were two 30-year-old service drones--"rones", customized by Lyle Campbell to improve their intelligence--that looked somewhat similar to Wall-E.

(Thanks @Tacroy for the link to the [episode list](http://www.tv.com/shows/space-island-one/episodes/) with brief descriptions.)

Comment: +1: The episode summaries I found [over here](http://www.tv.com/shows/space-island-one/episodes/) are a bit vague, but Season 1 Episode 3 seems a good fit for "found a rock from another planet that melts the station" (and matches your description of "microbe eats acrylic"), S2 E5 fits "shuttle crashed and everyone died", S1 E7 might be "mysterious pyramid" and S2 E7 seems to be a perfect match for the "smallpox" episode.

Comment: @Paul, I think you did it. That must the show I was looking for. Thank you very much. So sorry for the delay on response. I didn't even remember that I posted this question. I googled about the show today and came across this post. I thought someone posted it and turned out it was me (LOL at me).

Comment: @Tacroy Big thank to you too!