# Television series about scientists doing research on a space station

Tags: story-identification, tv

I think it was aired in the 1990s. A group of scientists are doing research on a space station. One of the characters finished in the Physics department then became interested in molecular biology and artificial intelligence. He grow some plants in one part of space station. He had two sophisticated robots.

Comment: And the cut off demon strikes again?

Comment: Any additional details about the series?

Comment: This sounds hilariously similar to Mst3k.

Comment: I think it sounds hilariously similar to Doctor Who's [Dinosaurs on a Spaceship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaurs_on_a_Spaceship).

Comment: Did one of the robots have a "H" letter on his forehead by any chance, and was the other a huge face projected on a screen?

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [Space Island One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Island_One) from 1998.  Details from a [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31645/a-tv-show-about-space-station) might ring a bell.

Space Island One did feature a physicist, Lyle Campbell, and he was working to make two service drones more intelligent, and he operated a garden/greenhouse.

(Does this count as a duplicate question?)

Comment: Only if accepted.

Answer (score 2):

could that be Space: 1999? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_1999 Just a guess off the top of my head...